# Testing responsiveness of HTML page using Java

Tags: java, html, responsive-design

I am developing an application to test whether a HTML page is responsive or not. Right now, I am assuming that using media queries is the only way to make a HTML page responsive.
But I am using a very crude logic to test it. I am parsing the HTML file and reading it for the presence of a media query statement. If its present I am declaring it as responsive, otherwise non-responsive.
Is there any other way I can go about it?
Is there any other test I can perform before declaring it as responsive or non-responsive?

Answer (score 0):

Check if they are using hard coded px instead of % or em. Maybe see if text is too small or links to close together.

At the end of the day it wont be a great resource for responsive checking since there are so many factors

Comment: Since I know that almost all the time in my case, instead of using a fluid grid-content coded specifically with relative sizing such as percentages, media queries are being used,I am ignoring % wise size testing. The main problem or ineffectiveness while developing this application is media queries can be used in different ways, even if they are being in the same way and I am just matching a presence of string, a mere blank space or comma or any other character can ruin it for me. 
I am myself comparing for a hard coded string in my application, a simple mismatch can give elusive results

Answer (score 0):

According to Ethan Marcotte's seminal article that introduced Responsive Web Design (http://alistapart.com/article/responsive-web-design), a responsive page will use media queries, flexible grid layouts and responsive text.

**But, even if a page has these elements, it doesn't mean that it is using them correctly. A responsive page is not one that simply uses media queries.**

I'm not sure that the ability to programmatically determine if a page is built responsively is even a viable goal. You can check for ingredients, but that won't tell you if the right recipe was followed.

Also, why have you tagged this question with Java?

Comment: I have thousands of HTML templates that I don't want to open in browser, hit F12 and then resize to check if it is responsive or not. 
Also, those files have clear bifurcations, either they are not responsive due to absence of media queries or they are responsive, the chance of presence of media query and still being unresponsive is negligible so I can risk on the fact that presence of media query implies a proper media query ensuring responsive design.
I have tagged Java because I am developing the application in Java and was wondering if anyone has already tried something like this.

Comment: Thanks for the article @scott marcus

Comment: @AnkitSahay You asked if there were other elements of responsive web pages that you'd need to check for and I have told you that there are, but they won't be programmatically verifiable. Now your reply is that simply having the media query present is enough for you, so it seems that you have answered your own question.

Comment: I wished to hear other people's opinion too. As you said, viability of this application is not much and I had the same thought. So I invited if anyone had to say anything on the topic. Thanks for yours!